# Simple Email Subject Filtering (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, strings

This challenge took me forever.  I spent a lot of time messing with regular expressions, but couldn't get it to work.  I ended up coming up with this abomination.  If anybody wants to take the time I'm interested in simpler ways to accomplish this task. (I'm a brand new pythoner)

```
def is_stressful(subj):
    """
        recognise a stressful email subject
        we are looking for any of: all uppercase, or ending in 3 !!!, or 
        containing 'help', 'asap', or 'urgent' despite have extraneous spellings
    """

    import string

    flagged_words = ['help', 'asap', 'urgent']

    if subj[-3:] == '!!!':  # check for ending in at least 3 !!!
        return True
    if subj.isupper():   # check for uppercase
        return True

    stripped = "".join(c for c in subj if c not in string.punctuation) # get rid of confusing characters
    wordlist = stripped.lower().split(' ') # make the list to check

    for word in wordlist:  # first easy check, everything is spelled correctly
        if word in flagged_words:
            return True
    for word in wordlist:  # start the annoying check, getting rid of extra letters in flagged words
        r = 0  # our word list counter
        getgood = []
        badletters = []
        while r < len(flagged_words):  # start the loop
            for i, l in enumerate(word):  # going through each character
                if l in flagged_words[r]:  # checking for good letters
                    if l not in getgood:
                        getgood.append(l)  # no repeats except for 'a' in asap (don't know a good way for this)
                    elif l == 'a' and getgood.count('a') < 2:
                        getgood.append(l)
                else:
                    badletters.append(False)  # make sure we don't spell flagged words accidentally
            r += 1  # go to the next word in list
            i = 0  # reset letter counter
            if ''.join(getgood) in flagged_words and all(badletters):  # our final check
                return True
            getgood = []  # reset the loop
            badletters = []  # reset the loop
    return False
```

My tests:

```
print(is_stressful("H!E!L!P! its urGent asAP"))
print(is_stressful("asaaap"))
print(is_stressful("Headlamp, wastepaper bin and supermagnificently"))
print(is_stressful("I neeed advice!!!!"))
```

Thanks for any tips!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Improvements with a new solution:***

- `import string`. If the function is a top-level commonly used function - better to move that *import* at the top of enclosing module.
  Though in my proposed solution `string` won't be used.
- `flagged_words`. Instead of generating a list of flagged words on every function's call - make it a constant with immutable data structure defined in the outer scope:

  ```
  FLAGGED_WORDS = ('help', 'asap', 'urgent')
  ```
- empty `subj`. To avoid multiple redundant checks/conditions on empty `subj` argument, if such would be passed in, a better way is handling an empty string at start:

  ```
  subj = subj.strip()
  if not subj:
      raise ValueError('Empty email subject!')
  ```
- `if subj[-3:] == '!!!'` and `if subj.isupper()` checks lead to the same result.
  That's a sign for applying *Consolidate conditional expression* technique - the conditions are to be combined with logical `or` operator
- the last `for ... while ... for` traversal looks really messy and over-complicated.
  When trying to untangle that, your test cases allowed me to make an assumption that the crucial function (besides of trailing `!!!` chars and all upper-cased letters) should *catch*:

  - exact word match with any of the *flagged* words, like `urGent asAP` (test case #1)
  - exact word match with repetitive *allowed* chars like `asaaap` (test case #2)

  and should **not** allow strings that contain only words which combine both allowed and unallowed chars like `Headlamp` or `wastepaper` (though they contain `he..l..p`, `.as....ap..`) (test case #3)

---

Instead o going into a mess of splitting/loops I'd suggest a complex *regex* solution that will cover both *exact word matching* and *exact matching with repetitive allowed chars* cases.
The underlying predefined pattern encompasses the idea of *quantifying* each char in each *flagged* word like `h+e+l+p+` with respect for word boundaries `\b`:

```
import re

FLAGGED_WORDS = ('help', 'asap', 'urgent')


def quantify_chars_re(words):
    """Adds `+` quantifier to each char for further use in regex patterns"""
    return [''.join(c + '+' for c in w) for w in words]


RE_PAT = re.compile(fr"\b({'|'.join(quantify_chars_re(FLAGGED_WORDS))})\b", re.I)


def is_stressful(subj):
    """
        Recognize a stressful email subject
        we are looking for any of: all uppercase, or ending in 3 !!!, or
        containing 'help', 'asap', or 'urgent' despite have extraneous spellings
    """

    subj = subj.strip()
    if not subj:
        raise ValueError('Empty email subject!')

    if subj.isupper() or subj[-3:] == '!!!' or RE_PAT.search(subj):
        return True

    return False


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(is_stressful("H!E!L!P! its urGent asAP"))
    print(is_stressful("asaaap"))
    print(is_stressful("Headlamp, wastepaper bin and super-magnificently"))
    print(is_stressful("I neeed advice!!!!"))
```

The output:

```
True
True
False
True
```

Comment: That messy complicated loop I made was exactly why I posted this.  I'm glad you were at least able to decipher what it was trying to accomplish. (my test cases) the regex was my initial attempt, but I need a lot more practice understanding. Your code is very clean and concise.  I learned a lot from it.

Comment: Your quantify_chars is a very elegant solution. What was difficult for me with regex is returning proper results on the flagged words that were spelled with extra letters.

Comment: @spence, you're welcome, glad to help

Comment: `FLAGGED_WORDS` should probably be a `set`. As long as it contains only three words it doesn't matter, but it will probably contain more. And it's spelled qua**n**tify.

Comment: @Graipher, thanks for a spelling hint "qua**n**tify" (I also noted "recogni**s**e")

Comment: @Graipher A frozenset, in that case. There's a good reason to make it immutable.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest Just a little nitpicking: *recognise* vs. *recognize* is a British vs. American English thing. Depending on what you aim for, either could be correct.